# Using IComparer<> with delegate function to search

Tags: c#, search, delegates

This feels like a too easy question to be found with google, I think/hope I've got stuck in the details when trying to implement my own version of it. What I'm trying to do is to sort a list of MyClass objects depending on my Datatype object different search functions should be used.

I've had something like this in mind for the class Datatype:

```
class Datatype {
  public delegate int CMPFN(object x, object y);
  private CMPFN compareFunction;

  (...)

  private XsdDatatype((...), CMPFN compareFunction) {
      (...)
      this.compareFunction = compareFunction;
  }

  public CMPFN GetCompareFunction() {
    return this.compareFunction;
  }

  static private int SortStrings(object a, object b) {
      return ((MyClass)a).GetValue().CompareTo(((MyClass)b).GetValue());
  }
}
```

And later on I'm trying to sort a MyClass list something like this:

```
List<MyClass> elements = GetElements();
Datatype datatype = new Datatype((...), Datatype.SortStrings);
elements.Sort(datatype.GetCompareFunction()); // <-- Compile error!
```

I'm not overly excited about the cast in Datatype.SortStrings but it feels like this could work(?). The compiler however disagrees and gets me this error on the last line above and I'm a bit unsure exactly why CMPFN can't be converted/casted(?) to IComparer.

```
Cannot convert type 'proj.Datatype.CMPFN' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<proj.MyClass>'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Delegates aren't duck-typed like that. You can *create* an `Comparison<MyClass>` from a `CMPFN` but you can't use a plain reference conversion - either implicit or explicit.

Three options:

- Create the comparer like this:

  ```
  elements.Sort(new Comparison<MyClass>(datatype.GetCompareFunction()));
  ```
- Use a lambda expression to create a `Comparison<T>` and use that instead:

  ```
  elements.Sort((x, y) => datatype.GetCompareFunction()(x, y));
  ```
- Write an implementation of `IComparer<MyClass>` which performs the comparison based on a `CMPFN`

Note that the second approach will call `GetCompareFunction` once per comparison.

A much *better* solution would be to get rid of `CMPFN` entirely - why not just use (or implement) `IComparer<MyClass>` to start with? Note that that would remove the casts as well. (If you're happy using delegates instead of interfaces, you could express the comparison as a `Comparison<MyClass>` instead.)

Note that as of .NET 4.5, you can use [`Comparer.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh737198(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a `Comparer<T>` from a `Comparison<T>` delegate.

I'm not sure why your current API is in terms of `object`, but you should be aware that in C# 3 and earlier (or C# 4 targeting .NET 3.5 and earlier) you wouldn't be able to convert an `IComparer<object>` into an `IComparer<MyClass>` (via a reference conversion, anyway). As of C# 4 you can, due to generic contravariance.

Comment: ... surely you can't `new` an `IComparer` ?

Comment: @Richard: My bad. I've had my head in delegate land. Will edit. It's clearly much too early :)

Comment: I wonder if the [compiler apologized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts), as it should have...

Comment: @Richard: For extra LOLs, you *can* new up an interface... if it's a COM interface. It's extremely weird :)

Comment: As of framework 4.5, you can use the Comparer<T>.Create function to create a comaprison function.  I know it wasn't available at the time, but since this is a popular search result...

Comment: @jmoreno: Thanks, added.

Comment: And if you're stuck on a pre-4.5 version of the Framework, you can use the solution detailed [here](https://www.velir.com/blog/2011/02/17/ilist-sorting-better-way) (disclaimer: not my blog).

Comment: @JonSkeet COM and **everything about it** is extremely weird... :p

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
class AttributeSort : IComparer<AttributeClass >
    {
        #region IComparer Members

        public int Compare(AttributeClass x, AttributeClass y)
        {                
            if (x == null || y == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("At least one argument is null");

            if (x.attributeNo == y.attributeNo) return 0;
            if (x.attributeNo < y.attributeNo) return -1;
            return 1;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

You can call it then like this

```
List<AttributeClass> listWithObj ....

listWithObj.Sort(new AttributeSort());
```

Should work like you want. You can create a type-safe comparer class as well.

Comment: Why the lack of generics? The OP is clearly using generics in the original code, so I don't see any call to go back to `ArrayList` and the nongeneric `IComparer` interface.

Comment: my bad, it was early and there was finished (and maybe old) code. :) But it's the generic version isn't much different so far.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of overloads of `List<T>.Sort`, but there are none which take a delegate with the parameters you have defined (two objects).

However, there is an overload that takes a [Comparison<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) delegate, which you can work with your code with a few minor modifications. Basically, you just replace your `CMPFN` delegate with `Comparison<MyClass>` - as an added bonus, you get strong-typing in your `SortStrings` function, too:

```
static private int SortStrings(MyClass a, MyClass b) {
    return a.GetValue().CompareTo(b.GetValue());
}

public Comparison<MyClass> GetCompareFunction() {
    return SortStrings; // or whatever
}

...

elements.Sort(datatype.GetCompareFunction());
```